# read -a unknown option

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm executing shell commands using python script. This is the command:

```
ntpservlist=( $OMC_NTPSERV ) && IFS=',' read -ra ntplist <<< "$ntpservlist" &&  for i in "${ntplist[@]}" ; do echo "server $i" >> /etc/inet/ntp.conf ; done
```

When I execute the command using a script, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh[1]: read: -a: unknown option
Usage: read [-ACprsv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n count] [-N count]
            [var?prompt] [var ...]
```

But if I execute the same command using the command line, it executes correctly without any errors.

I'm using:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
```

to execute the command.

Comment: Hmm.. try doing `-r -a` instead of `-ra`. Shouldn't matter, but what the heck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interactive shell is `bash`, but your system shell, used by `Popen`, is some flavor of `ksh`. To use `bash` instead, use the `executable` option:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        shell=True,
                        executable="/bin/bash") # or whatever the right path is
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
```

Most of your command appears to be valid `ksh`, but one difference is that `read -A`, not `read -a`, is used to populate an array.